# Determine which share extension was used

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

Since the `completionHandler` on `UIActivityViewController` was deprecated in iOS 8, is there any way to determine which share extension/activity was used by the user?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to use the new handler **`UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler`**:

```
typedef void (^UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler)(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError);
```

Call it like this:

```
[yourActivityVC setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError){

}];
```

Additionally, if you're wondering about knowing what item was selected, you just need to ensure your activity items conform to the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol;

[UIActivityItemSource Protocol Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/index.html)

Comment: Hmm, weird. Apple doesn't mention this in the docs only in the API diffs...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

setCompletionWithItemsHandler is iOS8 only. If you need to support iOS6-7 then:

```
[yourActivityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){

}];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what we used in Swift:

```
    ...

    // Configure UIActivityViewController
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
        UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
        UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
        UIActivityTypePrint,
        UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard]

    // Show UIActivityViewController
    presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // Define completion handler
    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = doneSharingHandler

    ...

func doneSharingHandler(activityType: String?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) {
    // Return if cancelled
    if (!completed) {
        return
    }

    // If here, log which activity occurred
    println("Shared video activity: \(activityType)")
}
```