# UIActivityViewController completionHandler replacement

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using `UIActivityController` and recently learned that the `completionHandler` is deprecated on ios8

Can anyone explain this change, is using the completeionHandler a bad design ?
And is there another way to achieve this functionality ?

It is crucial for me to know when the `UIActivityViewController` was closed, since i want to present another popup afterwards and in the iphone opening a new popup while the previous is still open result in a crush.
I suppose i can set a timer in my custom activity before i call `activityDidFinish`and assume 1 second later it is safe to open a popup but this is obviously the wrong way to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25999647/659310) answer by `tdevoy`:

You just need to use the new handler **`UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler`**:

```
typedef void (^UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler)(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a custom UIActivity, you can just put the code in the `UIActivity activityDidFinish`.

Another option along these lines would be to create a subclass of the activity you're trying to perform and override the `activityDidFinish` method, call `[super activityDidFinish]`, then do you custom action.

A third (trickier) option, without touching the UIActivity, would be to create a subclass of UIActivityViewController and override the `viewWillDisappear` method, however you would need some logic to determine whether an activity was performed or if the user is simply cancelling the activity.