# Objective-C UIActivityViewController method for when use is done

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using UIActivityViewController like so:

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[pdfData] applicationActivities:nil];

activityController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

I am wondering if there is a method I can use for when the use is finished using the `UIActivityViewController` (Cancel, Message, Mail, etc.)

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `UIActivityViewController` has a `completionHandler` property that you can set that gets called when its finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `completionWithItemsHandler` property of the `UIActivityViewController` to specify code that should run when the user is done with it.

Reference: [Determine which share extension was used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999553/determine-which-share-extension-was-used/25999647#25999647)